# How to right use promises and $q to handle asynchronous calls in Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-promise

I have code with following structure (pseudocode):
**Page init (app starts):**
**a]** getDateRange -> Get array of date range (for example array with 10 items)
**b]** getResultFromDatabaseForDateRange -> Assync task which return JSON object after each call

I would like to call method **b** in for each cycle and each returned JSON Array object store into class global variable. After receiving the all responses from **b** i would like to set whole filled object into scope.

Could somebody give me the example how can I do it in Angular right way?

Thanks for any advice.

I tried to do this by this way but it doesn't works (code is simplified because of length):

```
 $scope.getDateRange = function(direction) {
            console.log('Trying to set date range for ' +direction);
            switch(direction) {
                case 'today':
                    console.log("Trying to set date range for this week - "+countOfWeeksInPast+" weeks");


                    dateTo = moment().day(7).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    dateFrom = moment().day(1).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    console.log(dateTo);
                    console.log(dateFrom);

                    // CREATE THIS WEEK - 10 WEEKS RANGE IN PAST
                    for (var i = 0; i < countOfWeeksInPast; i++) {
                        var row = {};
                        if(i==0) {
                            row.ID = i;
                            row.DATE_TO = dateTo;
                            row.DATE_FROM = dateFrom;
                            dateRanges.push(row);
                        } else {
                            row.ID = i;
                            row.DATE_TO = dateTo = moment(dateTo).subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                            row.DATE_FROM = dateFrom = moment(dateFrom).subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                            dateRanges.push(row);
                        }
                    }


                    $scope.getResultFromDatabaseForDateRange('create_new').then(function(result){
                        // THIS GIVES THE VALUE:
                        //alert("Result is" + JSON.stringify(result));
                        console.log("Returned Result is: " + JSON.stringify(result));
                        //return result;
                    }, function(e){
                        $ionicLoading.show({
                            template: $translate.instant('ERROR_DATABASE'),
                            duration:1000
                        });
                    });

            }
        };

        $scope.getResultFromDatabaseForDateRange = function(listAction) {
            console.log('trying to get data for selected date ranges');
            // SHOW LOADING MESSAGE
            $ionicLoading.show({
                template: 'Loading data'
            });

            var deferred = $q.defer();


            // INSTANTIATE DB CONNECTION
            db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name:"callplanner"});
            var ic=0;

            for(ic; ic < dateRanges.length; ic++) {
                var sqlQuery =
                    "SELECT '"+dateRanges[ic].DATE_FROM+"' as DATE_FROM, "+
                    " '"+dateRanges[ic].DATE_TO+"' as DATE_TO, "+
                    " COUNT(*) AS DIALS_CNT, "+
                    " SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = '"+CALL_RESULT_STATE_APPT+"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '"+APPT_CNT+"', "+
                    " SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = '"+CALL_RESULT_STATE_CONV_NO_APPT+"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '"+CONVERS_CNT+"' , "+
                    " SUM(CASE WHEN dc.call_result = '"+CALL_RESULT_STATE_CANNOT_REACH+"' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '"+CANNOT_REACH_CNT+"' "+
                    " FROM "+DIALED_CALLS_TABLE+" dc "+
                    " WHERE  dc.date BETWEEN '"+dateRanges[ic].DATE_FROM+"' AND '"+dateRanges[ic].DATE_TO+"';";

                console.log(sqlQuery);

                db.transaction(function(tx) {
                    // init empty array for results
                    tx.executeSql(sqlQuery, [], function(tx,results){
                        for (var i=0; i < results.rows.length; i++){
                            row = results.rows.item(i);
                            //Udpate date for writeout
                            //row.DATE = moment(row.DATE).format('ddd DD.M');
                            //row.SUCCES_RATE = DialsCompute.computeSuccessRateDaily(row);
                            listData.push(row);
                            console.log("row is " + JSON.stringify(row));

                        }
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(listData));
                    });

                },function (e) {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
                    deferred.reject(e);
                });

            }
            deferred.resolve(row);
            $ionicLoading.hide();
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of rows processed, and when it is equal to number of rows needs to be read, you should resolve your promise. So in your case:

```
var numberOfProcessed = 0;
for(ic; ic < dateRanges.length; ic++) {
                var sqlQuery ="..."

                db.transaction(function(tx) {
                    // init empty array for results
                    tx.executeSql(sqlQuery, [], function(tx,results){
                        //process your result from sql
                        numberOfProcessed++;
                        if(numberOfProcessed == dateRanges.length){
                          deferred.resolve(resultObject); // resolve your promise when you are sure you handled everything
                        }
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(listData));
                    });

                },function (e) {
                    console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
                    deferred.reject(e);
                });

            }
```

And btw `getResultFromDatabaseForDateRange` needs to be part of a service, business logic, or connection to backend services etc. should not be part of controllers.

Comment: It seems to be fine. But i found, that each result item has a same DATE_TO and DATE_FROM.

Answer (score 0):

For my news ticker directive I have the following created:

```
   //method call
     fetchData($scope.verbs).then(function (messageModel) {
                $scope.messageModel = messageModel;
                $scope.toggleTimer();
            }, function (data) {
                $element.css("display", "none");
                $log.error("error: " + data.message);
            });

  //helper functions
        function fetchData(verbs) {
            return checkRequiredVerbs(verbs)
                .then(getDataFromSource)
                .then(prepareMessages);
        };

        function checkRequiredVerbs(verbs) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                arrRequiredVerbs = configManager.baseUrl.split(/\/:/g);

            if (angular.isObject(verbs)) {
                for (var i = 1; i < arrRequiredVerbs.length; i++) {
                    if (!verbs.hasOwnProperty(arrRequiredVerbs[i])) {
                        deferred.reject({message: "Verb '" + arrRequiredVerbs[i] + "' is unknown"});
                        break;
                    }
                }
                deferred.resolve(verbs);
            } else {
                deferred.reject({message: "Wrong verb syntax!"});
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        };

        function getDataFromSource(verbs) {
            return messageLoaderFactory.query(verbs).$promise;
        };

        function prepareMessages(messageModel) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                tmpMessageModel = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < messageModel.length; i++) {
                messageModel[i].visible = (i === 0);
            }

            deferred.resolve(messageModel);

            return deferred.promise;
        };
    }}
```

In my case before fetching the data from service I have to check the input params. At first the function `fetchData` will be called. Inside this function the`checkRequiredVerbs` function will be called and returns an `Promise`. This promise will be transfer to the next function `getDataFromSource` and returns an another `Promise`. Lastly the function `prepareMessages` will be called. When something breaks all actions stop and the news ticker will be hidden.

The full project can you find [here](https://github.com/svesch/angular-newsTicker)